# MySQL constraint based on previous row value

Tags: mysql, constraints, check-constraint

I have 2 tables:

Table A:

```
AID
1
2
3
4
```

Table B:

```
BID AID Status
1   1   Open
2   2   Open
3   3   Closed
4   1   Open - don't allow this row until AID 1 Status changes to closed
5   2   Open - don't allow this row until AID 2 Status changes to closed
6   3   Open - allow this row because AId 3 Status is closed
7   3   Open - don't allow this row until AID 3 Status changes to closed
```

How can I constraint adding another row in B table, until I change the status for AID to closed.
Or should I move the Status column to A table? But even then how can I check in B  table the status of A rows?

Comment: MySQL does not enforce check constraints.  Your options then include using a trigger and/or a stored proc.

Comment: ..or build the logic into the insert

Comment: IF aid 4 does not exist are you allowed to insert with a status of closed?

Comment: Yes if AID 4 was not used yet it should be considered closed

Comment: Would building the logic into the insert be the best approach or using a trigger/stored proc?

Comment: Define 'best'!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By way of demonstration:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(BID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,AID INT NOT NULL
,Status VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'Open'),
(2,2,'Open'),
(3,3,'Closed');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----+-----+--------+
| BID | AID | Status |
+-----+-----+--------+
|   1 |   1 | Open   |
|   2 |   2 | Open   |
|   3 |   3 | Closed |
+-----+-----+--------+

INSERT INTO my_table (aid,status) 
SELECT 1
     , 'Open' 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM my_table a 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT aid
                   , MAX(bid) bid 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP  
                  BY aid
            ) b
           ON b.aid = a.aid
          AND b.bid = a.bid
      ) y
     ON y.aid = 1
    AND y.status = 'Open'
  WHERE y.bid IS NULL;

+-----+-----+--------+
| BID | AID | Status |
+-----+-----+--------+
|   1 |   1 | Open   |
|   2 |   2 | Open   |
|   3 |   3 | Closed |
+-----+-----+--------

INSERT INTO my_table (aid,status) VALUES
(1,'Closed');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----+-----+--------+
| BID | AID | Status |
+-----+-----+--------+
|   1 |   1 | Open   |
|   2 |   2 | Open   |
|   3 |   3 | Closed |
|   4 |   1 | Closed |
+-----+-----+--------+

INSERT INTO my_table (aid,status) 
SELECT 1
     , 'Open' 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM my_table a 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT aid
                   , MAX(bid) bid 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP  
                  BY aid
            ) b
           ON b.aid = a.aid
          AND b.bid = a.bid
      ) y
     ON y.aid = 1
    AND y.status = 'Open'
  WHERE y.bid IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----+-----+--------+
| BID | AID | Status |
+-----+-----+--------+
|   1 |   1 | Open   |
|   2 |   2 | Open   |
|   3 |   3 | Closed |
|   4 |   1 | Closed |
|   5 |   1 | Open   |
+-----+-----+--------+
```